# Foreign key missing parenthesis

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
    EID CHAR(3) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ENAME VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    JOB_TYPE VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    MANAGER CHAR(3) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(EID),
    HIRE_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
    DNO INTEGER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(DNO),
    COMMISSION DECIMAL(10,2),
    SALARY DECIMAL(7,2) NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT (
    DNO INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    DNAME VARCHAR(50),
    LOCATION VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT('NEW DELHI')
);
```

in creation of the employee table
this is giving me an error of right parenthesis
and the department table is already created

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: if this is sql server you must ommit last comma on salary field

Comment: You've got a comma too many: `SALARY DECIMAL(7,2) NOT NULL,` <-- there

Comment: Delete last comma before last ')' where table completed. `SALARY DECIMAL(7,2) NOT NULL,`

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra comma in the line

```
SALARY DECIMAL(7,2) NOT NULL,
```

Delete that comma and the Employee table should be created.

> You need to Create the Department Table first to use one of its
>   Columns as **FOREIGN KEY**.

Also, **check your database**. There might already be a Department Table. To avoid getting that error when the table needed is already created, use the keyword `IF NOT EXISTS`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Department(
    DNO INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    DNAME VARCHAR(50),
    LOCATION VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT('NEW DELHI')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by the trailing comma, but you have other issues:

- The `FOREIGN KEY` is not needed for an inline reference.
- You need to define the tables in the right order.

So . . .

```
CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT (
    DNO INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    DNAME VARCHAR(50),
    LOCATION VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT('NEW DELHI')
);

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
    EID CHAR(3) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ENAME VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    JOB_TYPE VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    MANAGER CHAR(3) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(EID),
    HIRE_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
    DNO INTEGER REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(DNO),
    COMMISSION DECIMAL(10,2),
    SALARY DECIMAL(7,2) NOT NULL
);
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8ac41) is an example of it working.